# How to add color text in textform flutter?

Tags: flutter, text, colors, widget, background-color

[image]

I want to make a text form like this, how do I add color to certain text via regex?

Answer (score 0):

Please check flutter this sample code,

https://flutter.github.io/samples/rich_text_editor.html